# update product quantity in cart php session

Tags: php

I develop a new ecommerce site using PHP. I manage cart related data to database and store that data in session. The issue is when I add a product if the product is not in cart it adds that but if a product already exists it doesn't update quantity. This is my code for reference. I use key as product id

```
 
    $getUserTemp['products']=array();
    $mode=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['mode']);
    $productId=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['product_id']);
    $quantity=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['quantity']);
    $productData=getSingleProduct("SELECT id,name,
                                            quantity as quantity_in_stock,
                                            original_price,discounted_price 
                                    from `products` 
                                    where id=".$productId."");
    $productData['quantity']=$quantity;
    switch ($mode) {
        case 'add-to-cart':
            if(empty($getUserTemp['products'])){
                $getUserTemp['products'][$productId]=$productData;
            }else{
                foreach ($getUserTemp['products'] as $key =>  $value) {
                    
                    if($key == $productId){
                        $value['quantity']+=$quantity;
                        $value[$productId]=$value;
                    }else{
                        $getUserTemp['products'][$productId]=$productData;
                    }
                }
            }
            mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE `session_cart` set session_data='".json_encode($getUserTemp)."' where user_id='".$currentLoggedUserId."'");
    
               
            print_r($getUserTemp);
             break;
    }
```

My array data:

```
Array
(
    [user] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [profile_id] => 6
            [user_name] => bala@mail.com
            [role] => user
            [password] => $2y$10$bL4LybXcOX6nkEgRAM6Jjerrz2czEZJLWv7W1MNg.vWscb39NEsx2
        )

    [products] => Array
        (
            [38] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 38
                    [name] => HP
                    [quantity_in_stock] => 33
                    [original_price] => 50.00
                    [discounted_price] => 40.00
                    [quantity] => 1
                )
            [8] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 8
                    [name] => ASUS VivoBook 15 (2021) Core i3 10th Gen - (8 GB/512 GB SSD/Windows 11 Home) X515JA-EJ362WS Thin and Light Laptop  (15.6 inch, Transparent Silver, 1.80 kg, With MS Office)
                    [quantity_in_stock] => 20
                    [original_price] => 50.00
                    [discounted_price] => 40.00
                    [quantity] => 1
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: It's just for college project. I just want flow to be work

Comment: Normally people use college to learn how to do things right!

Comment: Okay first I work the flow after that i added securities

Comment: You can not update `$value` from within the foreach loop like that. https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php: _"In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop precede $value with &. In that case the value will be assigned by reference."_ If you want to use that option, make sure you properly unset the reference after the loop.

Comment: @RiggsFolly i updated my code and use mysqli real escape  string

Comment: But why loop over all products to begin with for this, that is not really necessary. You are using the product ID as array key - so you can simply use `isset` to check, if an array entry for a specific product ID already exists. If so, you add to that value, and if not, you create that new array element at this point.

Comment: _i updated my code and use mysqli real escape string_ Did you not read the comment? Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187) There are no short cuts